# Django: queryset multiple conditions or gather into new object

Tags: python, django, object, django-queryset

I need to get all `Comment`s for all `Project`s that includes a specific `User`. Meaning, all comments for all projects that a user is member of.

A user can belong to many Projects, and each Project has many Comments.

How should this be done right? So far I have solved it in my template by creating a nested for-loop, but that's not good since I need to sort the result.

I'm thinking something like:

```
projects = user.projects
comments = Comment
for p in projects:
    for c in p.comments:
        comments.append(c)
return comments
```

...does not seem to work.

Any clues?

Comment: You may want to post your model structure, at least the relevant fields. You should probably use filter as suggested by Joe. This is not the right way to query models in django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
query = Comment.objects.filter(project__user=person)
```

If the Comment model has a foreign key to project which has a foreign key to user. This will involve a SQL join statement in the database. It's better to do this on the the database because it's far more efficient. Databases are designed exactly to do this.

Comment: Yes, I have a ManyToMany-relation called "users".